# Why does Martha's son have a cleft lip?

Tags: dark

The son of Martha and Jonas, whose name does not seem to be given in the series, has what appears to be a mild cleft lip. However, I have been able to confirm that at least two of the actors, who played him as an adult and a more elderly adult, do not seem to. Thus, unless the child actor has one, and they chose the child actor first and decided to adjust the others' appearance to fit, this was almost certainly an intentional artistic choice, or something to do with the plotline.

Why does their child, the Unknown,  have a cleft lip?

Comment: Are you asking why the actor's don't have cleft lips?  In the show, the 3 versions of the Unknown have cleft lips.  I've only known one person with a cleft lip, but surgery is usually performed on the child to close the gap, so as children the lip will be more obvious and it will close and look more like "a scar" as they get older, being harder to notice.

Comment: Just speculation, but probably the main reason was so that the audience would be able to deduce this is the same character at three different ages, which might be hard to convey otherwise since he doesn't talk about himself much. And it could also have to do with the fact that Martha is technically Jonas' aunt, so Unknown is the product of incest and that can cause birth defects.

Comment: I mean, a group of three similar looking characters (two of the actors are actually related) of different ages who always appear together,  on a time travel show, is not precisely difficult to figure out.